# Excel formula to count unique values in two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns and I want to get distinct count for each of the account codes:

```
Account         12    12    34   56   90  90   91  91   
Account code    a      b    a     a    a   b    a   a

Correct answer  2      2    1     1    2   2    1   1
```

For account 12 and 90 I want the total count to be 2 because although the account is both under 12 and 90 consecutively it is showing 2 separate account codes (a&b). For account 91 I want it to count as 1 only because the account code belongs to account "a" only. is there any excel formula i can use so that I can determine which account has been registered under 1 account code and which account was registered under multiple account codes? Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you already tried? Where do you stuck[?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/countif-function-HP010069840.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If all the pairs are unique then just count the amount of times that the number exists:

=COUNTIF (A:A, A1)

in row C, assuming numbers in row A, codes in row B and formula copied across row C.

If pairs are likely to exist more than once and you don't mind modifying (a copy of) the data then copy both rows together (to the end of the data, not the whole rows) and then use paste special (right click in say cell A1 in a new sheet) to transpose the data. This will give you the same data but vertically. You can then use excel's built in remove duplicates function on both columns to get unique pairs. This may work without transposing but I only ever use it on columns, try it on the rows first?

If you don't want to deduplicate the data then it can be done but the formula would be more complicated.